# What's up with the close reviews

Tags: discussion, moderation, vote-to-close

Yesterday I found 25 close votes waiting for review (after two other reviewers maxed out at 20 each) and this morning another 16 waiting for review.

Who's on a cleaning spree ? Or is this not something new ?

Comment: It's because I'm on holiday and don't visit the site as much. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've spent a few hours cleaning up the backlog of unanswered questions - there were about 200 a few days ago. Most of the close votes were accepted and we're now at 130 unanswered.